# Are Django permissions flat?

Tags: django

Looking through the django permissioning system, it seems like you can only say 
"this user has this permission"
and 
"this user has access to this thing"

but not
"this user has this permission for this thing"
and
"this user has this other permission for this other thing"

Am I missing something, or is this the case?
I just want to assign different levels of permissions for different objects.

Comment: Django doesn't include object-level permissions by default, although it has the hooks to add them.  There are a lot of third-party packages that do so; I haven't used any of them personally so I don't have a specific recommendation.

Comment: Check https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/ for those packages.